# PodioBadRequestError when creating a item via API [Invoice APP]

Tags: php, api, podio

I am creating a items into PODIO apps via API, I am able to create an item to 3 apps(Client, lineitem, and claim) but I am not able to create an item on Invoice APP, I am getting "PodioBadRequestError" error each time while I am doing same as I did on other apps.

I am using a PHP library.

Here is a part of the script that I am using:

```
$newInvoice = array('fields'=>array(
                'date-created' => '2018-07-23',
                'third-party' => '5',
                'due-date' => '2018-07-28'
              ));

Podio::setup($clientID, $clientSECRET);
Podio::authenticate_with_app($invoiceAPPID, $invoiceAPPToken);
Podio::set_debug(true);
$invoice = PodioItem::create($invoiceAPPID, $newInvoice);
```

Can you please have a look into my request and guide me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the values in the wrong format.
If `date-created` and `due-date` are Podio **Date** fields, then you must put the date in `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format and pass it to `'start'` key.

Try this,

```
$newInvoice = array('fields'=>array(
                'date-created' => array('start'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2018-07-23'))),
                'third-party' => 5,
                'due-date' => array('start'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2018-07-28')))
              ));

//third-party is an integer field
```

Comment: Is `third-party` is a text field?

Comment: Ohh yes third-party is an integer and I am passing a string, now I changed it to integer and it is working, Thanks, Man!

Comment: Glad to know that. Please mark it as answered. Thanks :)